# Run Symantec End Point DoScan.exe from command line using JAVA

Tags: java, antivirus, antivirus-integration, symantec

I have a web application where I am uploading files.
I have a Symantec End Point Protection installed. I need to run DoScan.exe from comand line using JAVA.

but certain forums suggests that "DoScan does not support the scan of single files or folders via the command line."

is it true ?

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the old version of doscan does not allow you to but according to the site there has been an [update](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/new-features-doscanexe-sep-ru6mp1) for this.

Comment: I am trying to execute DoScan.exe from command line uisng a java code. But the ".exe" is not getting executed. I have came across the post which said that Symantec Endpoint is generating daily log file at "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\Logs" in Windows. It is not logging any lines when i execute using my code

Comment: I made some changes in my code and now "Symantec End Point " scans a single file using command line. But I want to read log of scanned file for each upload so that i can check scan results.

Comment: @HardikMishra what is the command from the cmd to scan one file at a specific directory ? 

say i need to scan a file called "ron.txt" at the dir "c:\"

what comes after doscan.exe ?